# Is there any way to get enabled and disabled simple product of configurable product in Magenoto 2?

Tags: magento2, product, database, sql, enable-disable

Is there any way to get enabled and disabled simple product of configurable product in Magento 2.

I need to get all id of enable and disabled product by using SQL query or object manager approach.

Can anyone tell me SQL query to get all simple product of a config. product.

Answer (score 0):

By using SQL Query i will get both enabled and disabled images.

```
$sql = "Select child_id FROM catalog_product_relation WHERE parent_id = '".$_product->getId()."'";
$sqlresult = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

If anyone has other solution please posted here.